# bloquear acesso a um determinado diretório via htacess

Tags: htaccess, apache

Bom tenho uma pasta na raiz do meu site chamada de `logs`.
Dentro dela vou salvar os logs que erros personalizados que monte.

Bom preciso bloquear essa pasta para não ser acessa por ninguém, apenas por mim via ftp.

Porém o php pode criar arquivos com log de erros lá dentro.

Achei várias formar de colocar senha nela com htacess, porém não quero por senha, quero bloque ela definitivamente para não ser acessada via browser.

Tem alguma forma de fazer isso com htacess?

Estou usando o apache.

Eu tentei fazer assim:

```
<Directory "Logs">
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Porém deu erro interno no servidor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bloquear o acesso completamente**

Criar o ficheiro .htaccess dentro da pasta que se pretende proteger

```
Deny from all
```

NOTA: inclusive, nenhum script tem acesso a esta pasta

**Bloquear o acesso parcialmente**

Criar o ficheiro .htaccess dentro da pasta que se pretende proteger

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Indexes
</IfModule>
```

NOTA: Ao aceder à pasta através do browser dá acesso negado (error 403), no entanto, o PHP consegue ter acesso.

Comment: dentro dessa pasta vai ficar alguns logs, preciso que o php tenha permissão para criar os arquivos. se eu usar o `Deny from all` o php vai ter essa permissão?

Comment: @HugoBorges a resposta está de acordo com a pergunta original onde dizes "...não ser acessa por ninguém, apenas por mim via ftp". Reformula p.f. a tua pergunta.

Comment: Desculpa, esqueci de informar essa situação. Já alterei minha pergunta.

Comment: @HugoBorges atualizei a minha resposta. Verifica p.f. se funciona.

Answer (score 0):

entre no seu apache2.conf ou httpd.conf use a diretiva `Define` para apontar aonde seu pacote está instalado.

```
 Define INSTALL_DIR [diretorio a ser instalado]
```

Ex :
Windows

```
Define INSTALL_DIR c:\wamp64
```

Depois use a seguinte configuração.

```
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/Logs/">
   Deny from all
</Directory>
```

> Lembrando que `Define [nome] [conteudo]` 
>   então caso queira pode dar outro nome, ou procurar uma diretiva já configurada.
> **Quando for manutenir ou configurar Directorys tente sempre dar todo caminho da configuração**

Se não for Windows fale, mas acho que serve para Linux também.

Comment: dentro dessa pasta vai ficar alguns logs, preciso que o php tenha permissão para criar os arquivos. dessa forma o php vai ter essa permissão?

Comment: Sim o php tem acesso a criação de pastas lá dentro com essa configuração.

Comment: Bom dessa forma deu erro 500, estou usando linux, vou ver o que pode estar acontecendo. Mas vlw pela ajuda.